# How can I center my navigationItem.titleView when I add more buttons to the navigationItem?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationitem

I'm doing a tutorial that replicates Twitter's iOS app.

I have a `BarButtonItem` on the left, an `ImageView` in the middle, and an array of two `BarButtonItems` on the right. If the array is only populated with one button, the `titleView` is centered. If I add the other button, the `titleView` moves over.

I understand the issue lies with the width of the `titleView` as shown in the pictures at the end.

```
    let titleImageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "title_icon"))
    titleImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24)
    titleImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    navigationItem.titleView = titleImageView

    let followButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    followButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "follow").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    followButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24)

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: followButton)

    let searchButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    searchButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "search").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    searchButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24)

    let composeButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    composeButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "compose").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    composeButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24)

    // THIS IS THE PROBLEM
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem(customView: composeButton), UIBarButtonItem(customView: searchButton)]
```

`navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem(customView: composeButton)]`:

[image: Before]

`navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem(customView: composeButton), UIBarButtonItem(customView: searchButton)]`:
[image: After]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert a dummy button on the left side of the navigationbar just for balance. Make the button the same size as the searchButton and clear background.

Comment: I was considering that. Is that not a waste of resources? Or is the resource allocation so minuscule it’s irrelevant?

Comment: How about trying and checking it really works. and think about that after try